# Uniqueness of weak solutions of HAMILTON-JACOBI EQUATIONS (Evans PDE, P131)

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

In the proof of THEOREM 7 (Uniqueness of weak solution) in section 3.3.3 of the book "Partial differential equations" written by Lawrence C. Evans, there's a claim[image][image]
How you get equations (41), (42) and (43) is beyond me. I checked $\S$C.4, but only found the following listed

> Consider a family of smooth, bonded regions $U(\tau)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ that depend smoothly upon the parameter $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$. Write ${\bf v}$ for the velocity of the moving boundary $\partial U(\tau)$ and $\nu$ for the outward pointing unit normal.
>
> ${\bf THEOREM 6}$ (Differentiation formula for moving regions). If $f=f(x,\tau)$ is a smooth function, then
> $$\frac{d}{d\tau}\int_{U(\tau)}fdx=\int_{\partial U(\tau)}f\ {\bf v} \cdot\nu dS+\int_{U(\tau)}f_{\tau}dx.$$

How do we derive from this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an error as noted in the errata for the second edition, maintained on Evans' [homepage](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eevans/):

> **Chapter 3**
>
> [...]
> page 132, line 5: Change “C.4” to “C.5”

C.5 is about mollification; in particular you will want Theorem 7 of C.5.

Comment: (42) was obvious when I looked at C.5. I still don't understand (41) and (43), but thanks.

Comment: @nnn for (41), one thing you can do is write $Du^\epsilon = D(u*\eta_\epsilon) = u*(D \eta_\epsilon)$, and then (as $\eta_\epsilon$ is smooth) this for each component is the limit of finite differences $u * \frac{\eta_\epsilon (\bullet +he_i) - \eta_\epsilon}h = \frac{u(\bullet - he_i) - u}h * \eta_\epsilon$ and then you can bound with the Lip seminorm. The LHS of (c) is a  second order finite difference which should hint as to the relationship with (43) (its a little bit like (41))

Comment: Thanks to thinking about it since then, I understand (41), but I still don't understand (43). Can you tell me why I need $s>2ε$ ?

Comment: @nnn glad to hear; that's because mollification (in both space and time) is defined by integrating on an $\epsilon$ ball. If you allow $s$ to be too small, then $u^\epsilon(x,s)$ at these small $s$ would be defined by integrating on a ball that intersects $s\le0$, and then you can't use $(c)$ anymore/$u$ is not defined. $2\epsilon$ is not optimal but it works